# Soundcloud Redirects Https -> Http

Tags: soundcloud

I have a page using the SoundCloud js sdk to stream audio. The initialization looks like this:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: myId,
    redirect_uri: "https://" + window.location.host + "/soundcloud-callback"
});
```

The page uses `SC.whenStreamingReady`, `SC.get` and `SC.stream` in a way equivalent to the following:

```
// Wait for SoundManager
SC.whenStreamingReady(function() {
    soundManager.onready(function() {

        // Get track metadata and stream the track itself
        SC.get("https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + audioId, function(data) {
            SC.stream(data.stream_url, {...});
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is that `SC.stream` requests an https page (`"https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + audioId + "/stream"`) but is 302 redirected to an http page (http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/...). Audio still works, but I don't get a satisfying lock in my browser bar (and this one request is the only thing stopping that).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I looked at this a few months back and my guess is that it's not possible without using some intermediate proxy server. On the bright side, https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/ is happy to serve secure requests so you could perhaps run something on your own server that makes the api.soundcloud.com request and converts to HTTPS.

Comment: You could try `url.replace(/^http:/, 'https:')`...?

Comment: Hey Joel, this will be fixed soonish so you'll get proper redirect to `https`. Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @nickf: Unfortunately that doesn't work because it's sent as a 302 redirect which is followed transparently by any AJAX request -- you can't get the Location header out.

Comment: Thanks gryzzly, can't wait.

Comment: @gryzzly has this been solved?  I'm still experiencing this problem!

Comment: @DavidGarcia this has been fixed, please see the answer below. If you still experience problems, please show me the example URL, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed now.

Try navigating to a random track from https

```
 https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/82686108/stream?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID 
 // will redirect you to  
 https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/SQyhrPCMQJyQ.128.mp3?%some_uuid%&AWSAccessKeyId=%amazon_access_key%&Expires=%expires%&Signature=%siganture%
```

And with http

```
 http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/82686108/stream?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID 
 // will redirect you to  
 http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/SQyhrPCMQJyQ.128.mp3?%some_uuid%&AWSAccessKeyId=%amazon_access_key%&Expires=%expires%&Signature=%siganture%
```