# SoundCloud API redirecting to https stream URL

Tags: http, https, soundcloud

since a few days Soundcloud seems to be redirecting the stream urls all to https stream links. Since our project is reworking the soundcloud responses for streaming devices, which do not support streaming over https I want to find out how to get the http stream url.

It does not matter if I call **https://** api.soundcloud.com/tracks/9479080/stream or **http://** api.soundcloud.com/tracks/9479080/stream?

both versions redirect to a https streaming url. If I resolve the streaming URL before, it just does not work sometimes. (get http 401 error),

Please help

Comment: I guess you could *not* follow the redirect and instead rewrite the Location header to http manually.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I resolved the URLs until there is no more redirection and afterwards replace the https by http in the URL. But this seems to mix up the authentication sometimes. It does work for tracks that have been on Soundcloud for a longer time, but all newly added tracks result in a http 401 error.

Comment: On an older post, it was mentioned that http api requests redirect to http responses (so do https requests to https responses) but this does not longer seem to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305674/soundcloud-redirects-https-http?rq=1